# hierarchical query with info about on which value is based on

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I'm trying write a hierarchical code which except all child/parent account will present also a column with an account on which id from table TO_DELETE this  account(child/parent) based.
In other words: Based on which account from table TO_DELETE you display parent/child account?

My code looks:

```
WITH acc_to_delete( ID ) AS (
                            select parentaccount from account where accountid in                                          
                                 (select accountid from to_delete )
                          )
                          SELECT accountid id_acc
                          FROM   account p
                          START WITH
                            EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
                                    FROM   to_delete w
                                    WHERE  p.accountid = w.accountid
                                    )
                          CONNECT BY accountid = PRIOR parentaccount
                          union
                          SELECT accountid id_acc
                          FROM   account p
                          START WITH
                            EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
                                    FROM   to_delete w
                                    WHERE  p.accountid = w.accountid
                                    )
                          CONNECT BY prior accountid = parentaccount
```

It seems to works fine. As result I got a tree account. At least I think that : )

```
CREATE TABLE to_delete 
( accountid number);
CREATE TABLE account
( accountid number,
  parentaccount number)
```

So now when to_delete table contain data:

```
 3123,
  3443,
  5646,
  7563,
  3452,
  2346
```

And account contain:

```
Accountid   parentaccount
  3123          5533
  3443          3452
  5646          4342
  7563          1239
  3452          5533
  2346          1230
  5533          6474
  6474          1231
  1231          1293
  1293          null
```

Then output should looks:

```
accountid  based on
      3123   3123       
      5533   3123      
      6474   3123
      1231   3123
      1293   3123
      3443   3443 
      3452   3443 
      6474   3443
      1231   3443
      1293   3443
      5646   5646
      4342   5646
      7563   7563
```

and so on..
is it possible to do in SQL? Or do I need to use pl sql?

Answer (score 1):

Read about ``CONNECT_BY_ROOT` operator:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators004.htm#i1035022

For example in this query:

```
SELECT p.accountid, CONNECT_BY_ROOT p.accountid as based_on
FROM   account p
START WITH p.accountid IN (select accountid from to_delete)
CONNECT BY accountid = PRIOR parentaccount
```

for each row returned by the query `CONNECT_BY_ROOT p.accountid` will return a value of `accountid` from root row (in other words - from a row qualified by `START WITH` condition as a starting row of hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks kordirko ! : ) I have one more question, Could you take a look at my code for hierarchical query? I thought it is okay but there is some problems with duplicate, I'm not sure If I did that correctly ...